# CompleteableFuture execution order

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

Is it guaranteed that allOf’s whenComplete method is executed last?

I was thinking when the last future completes maybe its whencomplete (undeterministically) gets invoked later than allOf’s.

I.e. is this output possible:

A

Combined

B

```
CompletableFuture<String>();
          
   
   bFuture.whenComplete((s,e)->System.out.println(s));
       
       CompletableFuture<String> bFuture = new CompletableFuture<String>();
   
   aFuture.whenComplete((s,e)->System.out.println(s));
   
   CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture =
                       CompletableFuture.allOf (aFuture, bFuture, cFuture);
   combinedFuture.whenComplete((v, e) -> System.out.println(“combined”));
   
   
   aFuture.complete("A");
   
   bFuture.complete("B");
```

Comment: I think there are some typos in the code example. Please provide a tested [mre].

Comment: Not only are there (lots of) typos in your code, there is a reference to an undefined variable (`cFuture`) at a place crucial to the logic of the entire snippet and your question.